# Effect of defining _WINDLL in a static lib

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi

For reasons I'm not going to get heavily into, but boil down to complicated .props chains, I have a number of projects (All `C` compiled with a `C++` compiler), that in a `DLL` **solution,** still build static libraries, but define `_WINDLL`.  This is fixable, but not easily.

None of these projects will or ever will use MFC--or anything like it--but *one* project--an OS abstraction layer--does include Windows.h for sockets, mutexes, and threads.

There are no errors or warnings during compilation because of this, and the application seems to run fine, but it's an ancient beast, with hundreds of little features and no unit tests :)

My question is: do I **need** to fix these static libraries to not define _WINDLL?

EDIT:

More background would seem to be necessary although I think I have my answer:

The property sheet defining this is OUR property sheet, and it's part of a relatively complex system that allows us to build Release/Debug/Lib/Dll Arm/WinCE/x86/x64 Clang/MSVC with *relatively* little pain, but it does occasionally have its issues.  The property sheets are hierarchical and are used by both projects I work with and by projects I have no desire to touch.

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: @JonathanPotter - No.  Thanks--updated the question.

Comment: I think _WINDLL is something the compiler defines for you, to tell you you're being compiled as a DLL. I don't think it changes anything implicitly; your code would have to actually test for it via #ifdef.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - Ahhh, and it is being checked in a different solution which uses these same .props files.  Thanks.  I both hope and believe you are correct :)  I certainly didn't find it in the system headers, but I'm always reluctant to trust that as a "final answer" :)

Comment: "include Windows.h for sockets, mutexes, and threads" at least for "mutex" and "thread", I'd recommend `include <mutex>` and `include <thread>` instead.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don’t wanna trigger the C guys :). Plus it’s an OS abstraction layer. Pedal to the metal and all.

Comment: @zzxyz. - I'm not following you. `<mutex>` and `<thread>` are C++ headers, *not* C headers. What are you on about?

Comment: @JesperJuhl They are C guys, and I'm going to pull STL headers into their code?  I truly don't understand what's not to get about that causing a problem.

Comment: It is not a predefined macro like Jonathan guessed.  This comes from the "Windows Dynamic Link Library" property sheet.  Use View > (Other Windows) > Property Manager to see that.  Doesn't mean anything more than "this project builds a DLL that is going to be used on Windows".  You'll certainly lose elegance points for having it defined in a static library project but you'll probably get away with it.  Removing the property sheet would be wise.

Comment: @HansPassant - It is explicitly defined in one of OUR property sheets (I know, I know) that is used by projects I've never even looked at.  God only knows what those projects are doing with it.  I can't remove the sheet without major headaches, either.

Comment: _WINDLL might not be defined by the compiler, but it is defined by the implementation. Generally any identifier with leading underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved and its existence should be managed, if not by the compiler itself, the bundled runtime.

Comment: Surely your property sheets are under source control. So just find out, who added that property sheet to your project, or who added the `_WINDLL` preprocessor symbol to the property sheet, and ask for clarification. The commit message may provide some clues as well.